# Самое большое число из цикла

Tags: php, mysql, while

```
    $bonusnie = mysql_query("select * from data WHERE `client` = 'b2c' group by comment ORDER by id DESC");
while ($opr = mysql_fetch_array($bonusnie)) {
    $komn = $opr['comment'];
    $stikbonus = mysql_query("select * from data where `client` = 'b2c' and `comment` = '$komn' group by email order by id desc");
    $rik =  mysql_num_rows($stikbonus).' ';
    echo $rik;
};
```

Результат цикла выводит 3 2 12 1 1
Как выбрать из этого списка одно самое большое число? (в данном случае 12)

Comment: Зачем минусовать, лучше бы помогли, раз такие умные

Comment: Запихнуть всё в массив и воспользоваться функцией `max`. Разве это так сложно, что нужно писать в SO?

Comment: да, я не знаю, как это сделать, поэтому написал в SO

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать книгу по php, а не забивать ресурс тривиальными вопросами. А лучше даже книги по алгоритмам

Comment: поиск ответа не дал, значит до меня никто этого не спрашивал (будь даже вопрос супер очевидным), а после могут поискать и наткнутся на эту тему. вы я так понял помогать и не собирались - поэтому просто пройдите мимо, вас никто не принуждает. можете еще минус кинуть для потехи самолюбия

Comment: @Arthur, вы же не правы. Первая ссылка в гугле. Так сложно просто вбить в поисковике? Вы больше времени потратили на создание вопроса на SO, чем искали бы в Гугле... А что будет с заданиями посложнее? Будете на каждую строчку кода создавать +100500 вопросов?

Comment: Ваша задача решается 1 запросом к mysql, без всяких циклов с кучей запросов. Человек, вон в ответе, вам набросок предложил такого запроса.

Comment: Что бы не минусовали видимо надо задать вопрос более полно. И еще его могут минусовать потому, чот в цикле чтения из БД вы используете другой запрос в БД. Такого быть не должно в принципе, нужный вам результат БД может получить сама за один запрос, что бы вам с ним помогли надо точнее описать что есть в базе и что требуется получить

Comment: да блин хоть обминусуйтесь, найдется несколько добрых человек, которые помогут, мне до цифорок в профиле особого дела нет. господа любят самовыражаться таким образом - да пожалуйста. запрос я добавил в пост, всем, кто оказывает помощь, спасибо

Comment: Учитесь задавать вопросы. вы сейчас приняли ответ в котором лишь набросок правильного запроса и выше php решение. подозреваю, что вы приняли именно php вариант. А это не правильно, не надо решать на php задачи, которые могут быть легко решены одним запросом. Лучше бы пояснили сразу в задаче, что такое это число 12. это максимальное кол-во уникальных email на один комментарий или что то еще ? И вообще делать `select *` из таблицы ради получения количества записей это очень плохо, вы тащите на клиента огромные объемы данных только ради получения количества

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C одной стороны можно собрать все цифры и взять max() от массива

```
$arr = array();
while ($opr = mysql_fetch_array($bonusnie)) {
    $komn = $opr['comment'];
    $stikbonus = mysql_query("select * from data where `client` = '123' and `comment` = '$komn' group by email order by id desc");
    //$rik =  mysql_num_rows($stikbonus).' ';
    $arr[] = mysql_num_rows($stikbonus);
    //echo $rik;
};
echo max($arr);
```

С другой можно написать запрос, который вернет нужные данные

```
select count(*) as total,  client, comment, email
from data 
where 1=1 
group by client, comment, email 
order by total desc
LIMIT 1
```

и получить нужное число.

Answer (score 1):

Запоминать текущее максимальное и потом работать с ним:

```
$max = 0;
while (foo) {
    $actual = mysql_num_rows(bar);
    if ($actual > $max) {
        $max = $actual;
    }
}
echo $max;
```

UPD.: вот это значение у вас `$opr['comment']` приходит из другого запроса. Уверен, можно объединить два запроса в один и просто выполнить его. Сразу получите нужный ответ и гораздо менее затратно.

Comment: не знаю как добавить код в комменты, добавлю в главный пост вместе с первым запросом, спасибо!

Comment: @Arthur код в комментах пишется между обратными кавычками (которая на букве Ё на клаве)